# How to quickly get a screen pixel color in Java?

Tags: java, performance, colors, get, pixel

I wanted to check if a pixel on my whole (1366*768) screen had a specific color so I made this :

```
for(int i=0;i<1366;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<768;j++)
    if (robot.getPixelColor(i, j).equals(couleur))
      System.out.println("couleur trouvée en ("+i+","+j+")");
```

which works but is WAY too slow.

Is there a function like getPixelColor but faster or another way to do please ?

Thanks you.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this? Are you attempting to take a screen shot? If so, there is a `Robot` function for taking one as a `BufferedImage`. Another suggestion, is take a screen shot, and use a seperate thread to process the BufferedImage.

Comment: You could use the JNA.

Comment: I think you shoud take bufferedImage with robot and then Scan buffered image for color.You can put that into for loop and it shoud be faster.Matt Clark had a good point there.

Comment: Have you tried multi threading it?